# Why is the HITBTC V2 REST API returning a 2001 error (Incorrect Pair)?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to place an order using V2 of the HITBTC API (docs [here](https://api.hitbtc.com/#create-new-order)). I'm trying to place an order via a POST request, and everything is fine authorization wise, but upon placing the order, the following function returns what the server is sending back, which is the following JSON:

```
{'error': {'code': 2001, 'message': 'Symbol not found', 'description': 'Try get /api/2/public/symbol, to get list of all available symbols.'}}
```

My issue arises with the fact that I'm passing the pair I wish to order in the format that's specified by [this call](https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/public/symbol) for the symbols, which returns JSON like the following:

`{"id":"NOAHBTC","baseCurrency":"NOAH","quoteCurrency":"BTC","quantityIncrement":"1000","tickSize":"0.000000001","takeLiquidityRate":"0.001","provideLiquidityRate":"-0.0001","feeCurrency":"BTC"}`

I'm passing a string formatted exactly as 'id' is formatted.

```
def HITBTCorder(pair, side, quantity, price, session): 
'''
Creates an order on HITBTC, returns status (filled or not filled)
Side: 'buy' or 'sell'
'''
orderData = json.dumps({'symbol': pair, 'side': side, 'quantity': quantity, 'price': price})
print(orderData)
response = session.post('https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/order', data = orderData)
responseDict = json.loads(response.text)
return responseDict
```

The code I'm running looks like this:

```
session = requests.session()
session.auth = ('APIPUBLIC', 'APISECRET')

response = trade.HITBTCorder("NOAHBTC", 'buy', 1000, tickers.HITBTCprice("NOAHBTC"), session)
```

Any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You may replace

```
orderData = json.dumps({'symbol': pair, 'side': side, 'quantity': quantity, 'price': price})
```

to:

```
orderData = json.dumps({'symbol': pair.lower(), 'side': side, 'quantity': quantity, 'price': price})
```

because `symbol` is required to be sent as **lowercase**.

Answer (score 0):

Data needs to be URL encoded in request body (quantity=1&symbol=ETHBTC...) not JSON to be accepted by server, hope it helps :)

```py
import urllib.parse as parse;
data = parse.urlencode(yourparamsasdict);
```